# How can I change User_AGENT in scrapy spider?

Tags: python, scrapy, tor

I wrote a spider to get my IP from http://ip.42.pl/raw via `PROXY.` This is my first spider.
I want to change user_agent.
I got information from this tutorial http://blog.privatenode.in/torifying-scrapy-project-on-ubuntu

I completed all steps from this tutorial and this is my code.

## settings.py

```
BOT_NAME = 'CheckIP'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['CheckIP.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'CheckIP.spiders'

USER_AGENT_LIST = ['Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 5_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9B179 Safari/7534.48.3',
'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.3; ko-kr; LG-L160L Build/IML74K) AppleWebkit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30',
'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.0.3; de-ch; HTC Sensation Build/IML74K) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30',
'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.3; en-us) AppleWebKit/999+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Safari/999.9',
'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.3.5; zh-cn; HTC_IncredibleS_S710e Build/GRJ90) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/533.1'
    ]

HTTP_PROXY = 'http://127.0.0.1:8123'

DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'CheckIP.middlewares.RandomUserAgentMiddleware': 400,
    'CheckIP.middlewares.ProxyMiddleware': 410,
    'CheckIP.contrib.downloadermiddleware.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware': None,
}
```

## middleware.py

```
import random
from scrapy.conf import settings
from scrapy import log


class RandomUserAgentMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        ua = random.choice(settings.get('USER_AGENT_LIST'))
        if ua:
            request.headers.setdefault('User-Agent', ua)
            #this is just to check which user agent is being used for request
            spider.log(
                u'User-Agent: {} {}'.format(request.headers.get('User-Agent'), request),
                level=log.DEBUG
            )


class ProxyMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        request.meta['proxy'] = settings.get('HTTP_PROXY')
```

## checkip.py

```
import time
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.http import Request

class CheckIpSpider(Spider):
    name = 'checkip'
    allowed_domains = ["ip.42.pl"]
    url = "http://ip.42.pl/raw"

    def start_requests(self):
            yield Request(self.url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        now = time.strftime("%c")
        ip = now+"-"+response.body+"\n"
        with open('ips.txt', 'a') as f:
             f.write(ip)
```

This is returned information for USER_AGENT

```
2015-10-30 22:24:20+0200 [scrapy] DEBUG: Web service listening on 127.0.0.1:6080
2015-10-30 22:24:20+0200 [checkip] DEBUG: User-Agent: Scrapy/0.24.4 (+http://scrapy.org) <GET http://ip.42.pl/raw>
```

**User-Agent: Scrapy/0.24.4 (+http://scrapy.org)**

When I manual add header in request everything working correctly.

```
   def start_requests(self):
        yield Request(self.url, callback=self.parse, headers={"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 5_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9B179 Safari/7534.48.3"})
```

This is returned result in console with

```
2015-10-30 22:50:32+0200 [checkip] DEBUG: User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 5_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/534.46 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1 Mobile/9B179 Safari/7534.48.3 <GET http://ip.42.pl/raw>
```

**How can I use USER_AGENT_LIST in my spider?**

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: I'm not sure. I found some solutions, and I try to change this row "'CheckIP.middlewares.RandomUserAgentMiddleware': 400," with  "'CheckIP.middlewares.RandomUserAgentMiddleware': 5," and working. All requests are with different user agents.

Comment: the number denotes which middleware should be apply first, the default UserAgent middleware is also 400, so maybe they were not working together, it is ok if you change it to 5.

Comment: Two days I scraped the site. Every day the scraper got ~8000 links. One day ago I get this "Connection was refused by other side: 111: Connection refused.". I try to change user_agent list again but the response is same. I changed Bot name, added delay and response is same. What could be the issue? Is it possible the IPs are in banlist or other Thanks!

Comment: try using a proxy, banning is a possibility.

Comment: I'm using TOR and polipo, and the ips changed every 25 minutes. I checked and ips changed and everything looks ok., but not.

Answer (score 9):

if you don't need a random user_agent, you can just put `USER_AGENT` on your settings file, like:

**settings.py**:

```
...
USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.10; rv:39.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/39.0'
...
```

No need for the middleware. But if you want to really randomly select a user_agent, first make sure on scrapy logs that `RandomUserAgentMiddleware` is being used, you should check for something like this on your logs:

```
Enabled downloader middlewares:
[
    ...
    'CheckIP.middlewares.RandomUserAgentMiddleware',
    ...
]
```

check that `CheckIP.middlewares` is the path to that middleware.

Now maybe the settings are being incorrectly loaded on the middleware, I would recommend to use the `from_crawler` method to load this:

```
Class RandomUserAgentMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self, settings):
        self.settings = settings

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        settings = crawler.settings
        o = cls(settings, crawler.stats)
        return o
```

now use `self.settings.get('USER_AGENT_LIST')` for getting what you want inside the `process_request` method.

Also please update your scrapy version, looks like you are using `0.24` while it already passed `1.0`.

Answer (score 3):

In scrapy 1.0.5, you can set user-agent per spider by defining a attribute 'user_agent' in Spider or share the user-agent across all spiders with setting USER_AGENT. UserAgentMiddleware gets user agent from USER_AGENT settings, and override it in request header if there is a user_agent attribute in Spider.

You can also write your own UserAgentMiddleware to random assign an user-agent in response header, and set the priority smaller than 400.